# Changing dictionary ordering in Python (Django)

Tags: python, database, django, dictionary

I have Python code accessing data in a database (in Django):

```
for result in request.user.results.all():
    for word in result.word.all():
        data.append(dict(zip([str(word.type.type)], [str(word.word)])))
```

which displays 'data' as such:

```
[{'color': 'blue'}, {'kind': 'pencil'}, {'rating': 'high'}, {'color': 'red'}, {'kind': 'truck'}, {'rating': 'low'} and so on....
```

I want to rewrite the python code to display this instead:

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'kind': 'pencil', 'rating': 'high'}, {'color': 'red', 'kind': 'truck', 'rating': 'low'} and so on....
```

Are these two the same or does the location of the '{' matter? I wrote the code above but I'm not how (or if I need to) modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your zipping together single-item lists to make single item dicts.  I think what you want instead is:

```
for result in request.user.results.all():
    data.append(dict([(word.type.type, word. word) for word in result.word.all()]))
```

`zip` is typically used to make dicts in situations when you have two pre-existing lists, not so much when you're constructing a dict from scratch from objects.

Comment: How would I exclude some values? For example, I do not want 'color' to be appended. I suppose I can add an if statement somewhere.

Comment: Yep, you can just add the if to the list comprehension. `... for word in result.word.all() if word.type.type != 'color']`

Comment: Yep. Just figured it out. Thanks